# Possible to get the count of var from "xml_grep --count" in one line?

Tags: shell, grep

This might be a stupid question, but I was expecting to just get the value "64" from my xml_grep statement below, but it's more verbose than I need.  I'm not seeing an option to get just the numeric count -- I don't want the path source echoed back.  Is there a trick to that, or do I need to try to get whatever number it shows after "total:" by some method in the countItems var?  Any tips appreciated.

```
$ countItems=`xml_grep --count //item http://10.0.123.456:8890/some/pagexml.htm`
$ echo $countItems 
http://10.0.123.456:8890/some/pagexml.htm: 64 total: 64
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on a possible 'fix' for the `xml_grep` command, but a (relatively) simple [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) can get you what you want:

```
$ countItems="${countItems##*: }"   # throw away everything up to the last ":" + "<space>"
$ echo "${countItems}"
64
```

**NOTE**: Assumes the `xml_grep` output always ends in `:<space><number>`